# Finding overlapping and calculation of min and max dates with in overlap in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can we find the between the overlap lap b/w the dates .
overlap means when start date and end date are within same range
for below example row 1  has no over lap.
Row 2to 5 can be considered as one set of over lap as there start date and end are over lap with themselves
Row 6 & 7 can be considered as one set of over lap
for eg. row 6 & 7 --> start date of row 7  is in same range  with respect to end date of row 6
so it becomes an overlap

Once overlap is found then and need to find out min(start date) and max(end date) and
want to assign a unique id to each overlap and in the **S.NO** column should show which rows are overlapped .Below is the I/p and O/p

---

I/p
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sample data *as text tables* would help.  Personally, I would also find a standard date format (YYYY-MM-DD) easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply and efficiently using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform a row-by-row comparison and aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id, start_date, end_date
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY start_date
  MEASURES  FIRST(start_date) AS start_date,
            MAX(end_date) AS end_date
  PATTERN   ( overlapping_dates* last_date )
  DEFINE    overlapping_dates as MAX(end_date) >= NEXT(start_date)  
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( sno, id, start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, DATE '2019-10-11', DATE '2019-10-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2019-11-04', DATE '2019-12-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2019-11-05', DATE '2019-11-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, DATE '2019-11-06', DATE '2019-11-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, DATE '2019-11-20', DATE '2019-12-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1, DATE '2020-01-01', DATE '2020-01-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 1, DATE '2020-01-15', DATE '2020-03-25' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | START_DATE          | END_DATE           
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2019-10-11 00:00:00 | 2019-10-11 00:00:00
>  1 | 2019-11-04 00:00:00 | 2019-12-20 00:00:00
>  1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-03-25 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=40b2419ad5b77cd97bc9ff3f222bad30)*

Comment: The `DEFINE` condition is the correct one when intervals are closed to the left and open to the right (as is generally considered "standard"). Looking at the OP's data, it is almost certain that his intervals are closed at both ends (otherwise his first row is an empty date interval). To fix that, you need to subtract 1 from the RHS - so that if two intervals end and then start on consecutive dates, they are fused together. Also, the OP wanted to give a unique ID to each row in the output. You can do that easily by adding `MATCH_NUMBER()` to the `MEASURES` clause.

Comment: @MT0 , thanks for the response , but match_recognize function is in oracle 12c , Can we apply some windowing clause to achieve this 11g